# AngularJs 2 failed to boot when generate all typescript file output to single js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, tsconfig, typescript1.8

I am using angular 2 with typescript (V-1.8) in my project. I have configured my tsconfig to generate output into single .js file. This file also have code to bootstrap application as boot.ts file also get transpiled in .js file. My application structure is as below.

```
Root
|_app
|   |  |__Module1
|   |    |_a.ts
|   |    |_b.ts
|   |__Module2
|   |___|_xyz.ts
|   |
|   |_Boot.ts
|_Js
| |_Deployment
|            |_single.js
|_index.html
|_package.json
|_tsconfig.json
```

In index.html I have added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Deployment/single.js"></script>
  <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
  <script>
   System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });

    System.import('js/Deployment/single').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
```

In code generated inside single.js looks fine. In node command prompt I seen error as in below image.

[Ts error 2661](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39F1G.png)

Hence application is fail to load. I am not getting any clue whether this is angular 2 error, syntax error or anything else. If I generate separate .js file per .ts file and modify index.html as

```
<script>
   System.config({
      packages: {
        app: {
          format: 'register',
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      }
    });

    System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
```

application works fine. Please help me to understand what goes wrong in single.js case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this github thread: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6468

For your convinience, user [sicaner](https://github.com/sicaner) suggests:

> I solve this problem by adding declare var Promise:
>   PromiseConstructor; on the top of promise.d.ts

Since this issue was closed, before modifying `promise.d.ts` you may try to update angular version - maybe fix will be already there.

Comment: Thanks csharpfolk. I updated angularJs 2 to 2.0.0-beta.7. Now promise issue is not exists. But  System.import('js/Deployment/single') still not working. At browser console  error is shown as SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: If error contains line number and file name try to check that file, if not try to use some online validator for single.js file. Please provide more info

Comment: error is showing inside polyfill file. Not in single.js